# jQuery on 'remove' event trigger

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use a trigger when an element is removed

I used this from the **jQueryUI** library

```
$('.int_modal').on('remove', function() {
    console.log("modal removed");
});
```

but it does nothing.

I did try changing `on` to `bind` which had no effect either.

I have a function which dynamically creates the element

```
function LoadModal(page, action, hide_close) {
    window.stop();
    
    action = action || '';
    hide_close = hide_close || '';
    
    var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
    
    $( "body" ).append('<div class="modal int_modal" id="modal_page_'+ i +'" style="overflow:scroll;"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="modal_close_button_'+ i +'">Close</button><h4 class="modal-title" id="modal_title_'+ i +'">&nbsp;</h4></div><div class="modal-body" id="modal_page_body_'+ i +'"></div></div><!-- /.modal-content --></div><!-- /.modal-dialog --></div><!-- /.modal -->');
    
    $( "#modal_page_" + i ).fadeIn("fast");
    //$( "#modal_title_" + i ).html(title);
    
    $( "#modal_page_body_" + i ).html('<h2 id="headingLoading" align="center">Loading...</h2><p align="center"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x"></i></p>');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#headingLoading').text("Still Loading...");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#headingLoading').text("This is taking longer than normal, but we're working on it...");
        }, 5000);
    }, 5000);
    
    if(hide_close == '1') {
        $("#modal_close_button_" + i).remove();
    } else {
        if(action === '1') {
            // automatically close
            // and reload
            CloseModal(i);
        }
        else if(action === '2') {
            // close on click
            // don't reload
            $("#modal_close_button_" + i).click(function() {
                CloseModal(i, '1');
            });
        }
        else if(action === '3') {
            // automatically close
            // don't reload
            CloseModal(i, '1');
        } else {
            // close on click
            // and reload
            $("#modal_close_button_" + i).click(function() {
                CloseModal(i);
            });
        }
    }
    
    $("#modal_page_body_" + i).load(page, function(){
        Initiate();
    });
}
```

and then another function which removes it:

```
function CloseModal(i, stop_reload) {
    i = i || '';
    stop_reload = stop_reload || '';
    
    if(i === "") {
        $("#modal_page").fadeOut();
        $(".int_modal").each(function( index ) {
            if($(this).hasClass("stop_auto_close")) {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                $(this).fadeOut(function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                }); // remove after fadeOut
            }
        });
    } else {
        var modal = $('#modal_page_' + i);
        modal.fadeOut(function() {
            modal.remove();
        }); // remove after fadeOut
    }
    
    // if stop_reload == '1', then DON'T reload
    // else, ignore and reload
    if(stop_reload != '1') {
        location.reload();
    }
}
```

I just changed my code to this:

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeRemoved', '.int_modal', function() {
    //alert("I, " + this.id + " am being deleted");
});
```

Which is working on `remove` however, when the function `LoadModal()` is called, it shows me the alert x3 times (then once when it's removed)

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: none at all, i just changed to `$('body').on('DOMNodeRemoved', '.int_modal', function() {` instead which is working although when the element is created (dynamically) it's triggering 3 times and then once more when removed. I'll update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native `remove` event (`DOMNodeRemoved` is deprecated and may disappear). But you can generate one if you want to use an event listener.

The simple jQuery way to do this would be
`$('body').trigger('removed');` at the and of your `CloseModal` function

If you need the id of the modal that you closed then pass it with the event `$('body').trigger('removed', i);` and in your listener

```
$('body').on('removed', function(evt, data) {
    console.log("modal removed: ", data);
});
```

Comment: just tested this, and it's actually removing the whole `body` tag

Comment: Try changing the event name. Looks like jQuery uses `remove` already. I have edited my answer.

Comment: yeah, tried `modal_remove` and it works perfectly :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here i simulate event remove by testing if selector is destroyed:

```js
var nbSelector = -1;
var selector = ".remove";
var timer = setInterval(testifsomethingisremoved, 500, selector);


$('#but').on('click', function(){
  clearInterval(timer);
});



function testifsomethingisremoved(){

  var nbsl = $(selector).length;
  if(nbSelector < 0) nbSelector = nbsl;

  // if there is no selector defined, donothing
  if(nbsl == 0 && nbSelector == 0) {
    nbSelector = -1;
    return;
  }

  //if a selector is destroyed, alert and clear interval
  if(nbsl < nbSelector){
    //here i stop timer or do other thing
    clearInterval(timer);

   $(document).trigger('tagRemoved', selector);
  }
}

$(document).on('tagRemoved', function(e, data) {
  alert('Tag with class ' + data + ' removed!');
});

// to test destroy after 2 sec
setTimeout(function(){
  $(selector).remove();
  console.log("removed!");
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="but" type="button">stop the timer</button>

<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option class="remove" value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```